# How can I add this value as a query, inside of a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
Public void aMethod(String itemName, String theUsersName){  

preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO items  (Owner_ID, Name, State)               VALUES         (?,?,?) ");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username     = ' "+theUsersName+"')");
preparedStatement.setString(2, itemName); 
preparedStatement.setString(3, state);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

}
```

username table contains usernames and id's
here I'm given theUsersName and want to find the id of that username, to set the Owner_ID of the new item in Item's table = theUsername's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inserting it into the original `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO items (Owner_ID, Name, State)
VALUES (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?, ?,?)
```

and replacing the first parameter with the actual value:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, theUsersName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try if it does not throw an exception, (*or otherwise I'll delete this*)

```
String query =  "INSERT INTO items  (Owner_ID, Name, State) " +
                "SELECT ID, ? AS Name, ? AS State " +
                "FROM   users " +
                "WHERE  userName = ? " 
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, itemName);
preparedStatement.setString(2, state); 
preparedStatement.setString(3, theUsersName);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this: using `INSERT INTO SELECT..`

```
INSERT INTO items  (Owner_ID, Name, State)
SELECT id,?,? FROM users WHERE 
username = ?
```

Or using subquery like this:

```
INSERT INTO items (Owner_ID, Name, State)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1),?,?)
```

Here you have to set limit to 1.

Comment: it requires `LIMIT 1` or else it will return *..subquery cannot return more than one row...*

Comment: `(SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You first have to fetch the Id from the users table then you can pass it.Have a look on :

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ' "+theUsersName+"'");
ResultSet rs=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
 if(rs.next())
int id=rs.getInt(1);
preparedStatement.setString(1,id);
```